# Can Salesforce Duplicate Management compare across objects?

Tags: duplicate-management

Is is possible for Salesforce Duplicate Management matching rules to compare across objects?

This article talks about cross-object duplicate rules:

https://focusonforce.com/configuration/native-duplicate-management-in-salesforce/

as does this Salesforce help page:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_rules_overview.htm&type=5

This article shows how to make them:

https://www.simplysfdc.com/2016/11/salesforce-duplicate-management-on.html

but it doesn't match what I see in the Salesforce matching rules screens.

When setting up matching rule criteria, there appears to be no way to select anything other than a field from the current object.

Is this a feature that needs to be enabled somehow or that existed and was withdrawn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is that you specify the object to compare with in the Duplicate rule, not in the Matching rule. The matching rule only defines the fields and the logic to use for comparison.

[image]